# Error E0277 following book example dyn Trait, how to push a dyn trait in vector?

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects, sized-box

My real case is similar to the Rust doc about dyn trait with Screen and Draw trait.
So I built an example totally similar to the book. But instead of initializing the vector in place, I need to have a register function to push components into the vector. But I get error: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Draw`
I don't understand how to fix it...

```rust
pub trait Draw {
    fn draw(&self);
}
pub struct Screen {
    pub components: Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>,
}

impl Screen {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Screen {
            components: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
    fn register(&mut self, w: &dyn Draw) {
        self.components.push(Box::new(*w));
    }
    fn show(&self) {
        for d in self.components {
            d.draw()
        }
    }
}

struct TextBox {
    txt: String,
}
impl TextBox {
    fn new(t: &str) -> Self {
        TextBox { txt: t.to_string() }
    }
}

struct Button {
    label: String,
}
impl Button {
    fn new(l: &str) -> Self {
        Button {
            label: l.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

impl Draw for TextBox {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.txt.as_str())
    }
}
impl Draw for Button {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.label.as_str())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Screen::new();
    let b = Button::new("Button1");
    let t = TextBox::new("Some text");
    s.register(&b as &dyn Draw);
    s.register(&t as &dyn Draw);
    s.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't dereference a `&dyn Trait` because that would create something of unknown size on the stack.
Instead you can take `impl Trait` and box it up or take `Box<dyn Draw>` directly:

```rust
    fn register(&mut self, w: impl Draw + 'static) {
        self.components.push(Box::new(w));
    }
```

and pass in the objects themselves instead of references to them:

```rust
    let b = Button::new("Button1");
    let t = TextBox::new("Some text");
    s.register(b);
    s.register(t);
```

Note: the `+ 'static` means that `w` can't contain any references shorter than `'static` it does **not** mean that `w` has to live forever.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works but now I hit another problem. Calling register on b and then t causes a borrow issue. I will post another example where I found a hack around, but I find it a bit ridiculous.